# How to search django Postgres table textarea field for multiple words?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am creating a recruitment website, and i need to search a keys skills text area field, for multiple values.

eg. I may be looking for a C++ programmer with good python, and worked in healthcare data scientist.

so my search entry form i would put c++ python healthcare data scientist.

there could be up to 20 staff performing searches against a database with a few thousand records. I need to know what is the best technology to perform this type of search with Django and postresql database hosted on digitalocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to use Django with PostgreSQL Full-Text Search.

In my opinion it's the best solution because you will have the data and the search indexes directly inside *PostgreSQL* and you will not be forced to install and maintain additional software (such as *Elasticsearch*) and keep the data and indexes in sync.

This is the simplest code example you can have to perform a [full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+postgresql+full-text-search) in Django with PostgreSQL:

```
search_entry = 'c++ python healthcare data scientist'
Person.objects.filter(skills__search=search_entry)
```

For all the basic **documentation** on using the full-text search in Django with PostgreSQL you can use the official documentation: **"[Full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)"**

If you want to deepen further you can read an **article** that I wrote on the subject:

**"[Full-Text Search in Django with PostgreSQL](http://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql)"**

Comment: Thanks, the information looks great; I am definitely going the FTS route, only problem is, I don't know if i am going off track, but I was thinking of using an ArrayField for the search box. Your brief example, i'm not sure if i should use an ArrayField for the search form, then get the data, split it into individual words and construct a query using query = CVStore.objecs.filter(Q(key_skills__icontains("python") | Q(key_skills__icontains("data scientist")) etc .. or if i should just create a text string and pass it into the query ?

Comment: You can use SearchQuery to apply boolean logic to text you want to search. But I think it's better if you accept this answer and then create a more specific question with additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the JSONB storage in postgres.  Which is NOSQL inside a SQL database.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html

How to access in DJANGO
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield